# Sending Push Notification to Ionic Service on Rails Controller Doesnt send message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ionic-framework, phonegap-pushplugin

So i amusing the Ionic Push API to send a notification and while i am receiving the notification, i however do not get the message included in the notification. Yes it is weird and i know that but i dont know why it is happening.

This is my code

```
   params = {
          "tokens" => ["DEVICE_TOKEN"],
          "profile" => "PROFILE_TAG",
          "notification" => {
            "title" => "Partners",
            "message" => "Hello World!",
            "payload" => {
              "$state" => "app.settings"
            },
            "android" => {,
              "content_available" => 1,
              "sound" => "default",
              "forceShow" => true
            }
          }
        }

        uri = URI.parse('https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications')
        https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
        https.use_ssl = true
        req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
        req['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        req['Authorization'] = 'Bearer API_TOKEN'
        req.body = params.to_json
        res = https.request(req)
        puts res.body
```

i get the notification but only the title shows up not the message. So im a bit confused on what i am doing wrong